# Moving mean reverting model - Beta off the charts? (Kalman Filter)

Tags: r, optimization, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I have implemented the moving mean reverting model with the FKF package, but unfortunately the beta as well as beta mean is way off as you can see in the chart. Is there anything I have not considered? Beta-mean (red) should normally run within the blue line and the values should fluctuate around the value 1 and not partly over 100?

Edit: Now it's the correct observation equation

\begin{align}
  r_t&= \beta_t r_{M,t}+\epsilon ,\space ~ N,\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})\\
 \beta_{t+1}-\bar{\beta}_{t+1}&= T(\beta_{t}-\bar{\beta}_{t})+\eta_{1t},\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{1t}})\\
 \bar{\beta}_{t+1}&= \bar{\beta_t} +\eta_{2t},\space  ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{2t}})\\
\end{align}

In matrix notation the state equation would be

$$\pmatrix{\beta_{t+1} \\ \bar{\beta}_{t+1}} = \pmatrix{T & I-T \\ 0 & I}\pmatrix{\beta_{t} \\\ \bar{\beta_t}}  + \pmatrix{\eta_{1t} \\ \eta_{2t} }.$$

Here is also the entire code that you can copy and paste in its entirety if you are interested. Rmt stands for market return and Rpt for portfolio return. I really appreciate any help.

```
returns <- data.frame(Rpt = c(1.48, -2.97, -0.86, -3.05, 0.93, 4.81, -6.27, 
                              2.48, 0.23, 3.19, 2.2, -0.32, 0.45, -0.96, -3.19, -1.82, 3.28, 2.69, 2.38, -1.57, 4.21, 0.52, 6.75, 7.49, -4.8, 2.26),
                      Rmt = c(2.26, 1.33, 0.73, 2.06, 2.36, -1.14, -5.97,
                              2.77, 5.01, 0.86, 6.25, -1.7, 4.98, -0.49, -5.02, 4.04, 6.74, 4.1, 7.33, -4.15, 5.35, -3.8, 2.98, 1.32, 0.15, 7.04))

# Moving Mean Reverting Model

y <- returns$Rpt
ct <- matrix(0)
dt <- matrix(0, nrow = 2)

#Zt as 3-dimensional Array due to time-varying specification
Zt <- array(t(cbind(returns[,2:2],returns[,2:2])), dim=c(1, 2, nrow(returns)))
# Starting points
a0 <- c(0,0)
P0 <- diag(2)*10^7

# Parameter estimation
fit.fkf <- optim(c(1.001, 1.001, 1.001, 0.5),
                 fn = function(par,...) -fkf(HHt = matrix(c(exp(par[1]),0,0,exp(par[2])),2,2,byrow=T), GGt = matrix(exp(par[3])),Tt = matrix(c(par[4],1-par[4],0,1),2,2,byrow=T), ...)$logLik,
                 yt = rbind(y), a0 = a0, P0 = P0, ct = ct, dt = dt,
                 Zt = Zt, check.input = T)

# Kalman-Filter
fkf.obj <- fkf(a0, P0, dt, ct, Zt, HHt = matrix(c(exp(fit.fkf$par[1]),0,0,exp(fit.fkf$par[2])),2,2,byrow=T),
               GGt = matrix(exp(fit.fkf$par[3])),Tt = matrix(c(fit.fkf$par[4],1-fit.fkf$par[4],0,1),2,2,byrow=T), yt = rbind(y))


print(fit.fkf$par)

plot(dropFirst(fkf.obj$att[1,]),type='l',col = "blue")
lines(dropFirst(fkf.obj$att[2,]),type='l',col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure your derivation of the state space model matches your original description, but aside from that, if you know it should be near 1, why did you set an initial state prior with a variance of 10^7?   I know it's common advice to just "set a really large value" but it doesn't really make sense when you actually know a lot about your target, and it's frequently numerically problematic. Just put a much smaller, more reasonable value.

Comment: Hi,  first of all, I want to say that I appreciate you responding. I think one problem I've discovered is that the matrix is not correct because the difference on the left side of the equation relates to $\bar{\beta}_{t+1}$ and not $\bar{\beta}_{t}$. But right now I don't know how to solve it and if it is the only problem. Regarding the start covariance, I have chosen the general method of diffuse prior. The beta should normally fluctuate around the value 1 even under such a covariance, at least in the value range from -1.5  to 1.5, since it is virtually a kind of CAPM here.

Comment: Does anyone perhaps have an idea how to deal with this difference term in the state variable? Unfortunately, bringing $\bar{\beta}_{t+1}$ to the other side of the equation does not work, since it is not constant.

Comment: Related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536056/mean-reverting-model-kalman-filter-where-is-the-mistake

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there's a number of issues here.

First of all, the state space form you derive doesn't correspond to the model you've defined. You say:

$$\begin{align}
 r_t&= \beta_t r_{M,t}+\bar{\beta_t} r_{M,t}+\epsilon ,\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})\\
 \beta_{t+1}-\bar{\beta}_{t+1}&= T(\beta_{t}-\bar{\beta}_{t})+\eta_{1t},\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{1t}})\\
 \bar{\beta}_{t+1}&= \bar{\beta_t} +\eta_{2t},\space  ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{2t}})\\
\end{align}$$

Define $\Delta_t = \beta_t - \bar{\beta}_t$. Then your model is this:

$$\begin{align}
 r_t&= \Delta_t r_{M,t}+2\bar{\beta_t} r_{M,t}+\epsilon ,\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})\\
 \Delta_{t+1}&= T\Delta_t+\eta_{1t},\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{1t}})\\
 \bar{\beta}_{t+1}&= \bar{\beta_t} +\eta_{2t},\space  ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{2t}})\\
\end{align}$$

The observation equation comes from the fact that $\Delta_t + 2\bar{\beta}_t = \beta_t + \bar{\beta}_t$.

In state space form, the state equation is then:

$$\pmatrix{\Delta_{t+1} \\ \bar{\beta}_{t+1}} = \pmatrix{T & 0 \\ 0 & I}\pmatrix{\Delta_{t} \\\ \bar{\beta_t}}  + \pmatrix{\eta_{1t} \\ \eta_{2t} }$$

You can then recover $\beta_t = \Delta_t + \bar{\beta}_t$. Here's what that looks like, added to the end of your code:

```
ct.alt <- ct
dt.alt <- dt
Zt.alt <- array(t(cbind(returns[,2:2],2*returns[,2:2])), dim=c(1, 2, nrow(returns)))
a0.alt <- a0
P0.alt <- diag(2)*10

fit.fkf.alt <- optim(c(1.001, 1.001, 1.001, 0.5),
             fn = function(par,...) {
               -fkf(HHt = matrix(c(exp(par[1]),0,
                                   0,exp(par[2])),2,2,byrow=T), 
                    GGt = matrix(exp(par[3])),
                    Tt = matrix(c(par[4],0,
                                  0,1),2,2,byrow=T), 
                    ...)$logLik
             },
             yt = rbind(y), a0 = a0.alt, P0 = P0.alt, ct = ct.alt, dt = dt.alt,
             Zt = Zt.alt, check.input = T)

fkf.obj.alt <- fkf(a0.alt, P0.alt, dt.alt, ct.alt, Zt.alt, 
               HHt = matrix(c(exp(fit.fkf.alt$par[1]),0,
                              0,exp(fit.fkf.alt$par[2])),2,2,byrow=T),
               GGt = matrix(exp(fit.fkf.alt$par[3])),
               Tt = matrix(c(fit.fkf.alt$par[4],0,
                             0,1),2,2,byrow=T), 
               yt = rbind(y))

plot(dropFirst(fkf.obj.alt$att[1,]+fkf.obj.alt$att[2,]),type='l',col = "blue",ylim=c(-1,1))
lines(dropFirst(fkf.obj.alt$att[2,]),type='l',col = "red")
lines(dropFirst(fkf.obj.alt$att[1,]),type='l',col = "black")
legend("topleft", legend = c("Beta","BetaBar","Delta"), col = c("blue", "red","black"),lty=1)
```

[image]

$\Delta_t$ doesn't really "mean-revert" because the estimate of $T\approx 1$.

Your second problem is that your optimization doesn't converge:

```
> fit.fkf
$par
[1]  -6.1269812 -10.0913240   2.2201529   0.9999626

$value
[1] 70.24941

$counts
function gradient 
 501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

The third one is that you picked a finite but unrealistically high state prior variance. Exactly diffuse initialization works, but large-but-finite variances can cause numerical instabilities. If you know the result should be between -1.5 and 1.5, a good finite "diffuse" value is like 10, not 10 million.

Issues 2 and 3 is why you get very weird results, and issue 1 shows that you aren't fitting the model you defined originally.

Edit: There's also a fourth issue, which is that neither your original model (above) or the corrected one (in the comments) allow identifying all the state components when $T=1$. Take $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ and define:

$$\beta'_t = \beta_t + \delta$$
$$\bar{\beta}'_t = \bar{\beta} -\delta$$
$$\Delta'_t = \beta'_t - \bar{\beta}'_t = \Delta_t + 2\delta$$

Then $\beta'_t + \bar{\beta}'_t = \beta_t + \bar{\beta}$ and:

$$\begin{align}
 r_t&= \Delta'_t r_{M,t}+2\bar{\beta'_t} r_{M,t}+\epsilon ,\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})\\
 \Delta'_{t+1}&= \Delta'_t+\eta_{1t},\space ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{1t}})\\
 \bar{\beta}'_{t+1}&= \bar{\beta_t}' +\eta_{2t},\space  ~ N(0,\sigma^2_{\eta_{2t}})\\
\end{align}$$

Since the resulting equations are the same and $\delta$ is arbitrary, you won't be able to identify it; the result will depend strongly on how you set the prior state mean (`a0`).

The corrected model has the same issue but with a slightly different transformation:

$$\beta'_t = \beta_t + \delta$$
$$\bar{\beta}'_t = \bar{\beta} + 2\delta$$
$$\Delta'_t = \beta'_t - \bar{\beta}'_t = \Delta_t - \delta$$

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply and the effort you put in. I really appreciate it. I unfortunately have an error in the observation equation at the beginning. It should actually be $r_t= \beta_t r_{M,t}+\epsilon$ . Maybe the result will be more plausible then. I'm afraid I still don't understand exactly from your code that it's a difference between $\beta$ and $\bar{\beta}_t$? According to the code, it looks to me as if there are two state variables that do not interact directly with each other via a difference.

Comment: I just pasted your code and ran it, but I get completely different values than in your plot.

Comment: I think $\Delta$ at the end of the Kalman procedure by subtraction is not the same as specifying the difference from the beginning, because already the intermediate results in the filtering process change by this.

Comment: The two state variables are $\Delta_t$ and $\bar{\beta}_t$ instead of $\beta_t$ and $\bar{\beta}_t$. I've just reparametrized the state as a linear combination of what you had before so that it would fit in state space form. Also see my edit for further issues.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment. I read in a paper that for numerical problems you can take the OLS estimator based on the first 10 observations and take that as the starting value.  What I don't know here is how corresponding variance can be obtained from an OLS estimator. That is, if T > 0 and T <1 holds, then the model is correct? I always compare the average of the filtered betas with the determined betas via the OLS procedure. Normally these should be close, but I often get a discrepancy. For example OLS Beta = 0.45 and Kalman Beta 0.7. This deviation is too large.

Comment: Hi Chris,
since you're an expert in the field, I was wondering if you might take a look at my latest question, since unfortunately I probably won't get an answer otherwise and have nowhere else to go.  I would really appreciate it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540504/capm-ols-beta-vs-beta-kalman-filter-random-walk-why-such-a-big-difference